# Mozilla doesn't read video

Tags: html, firefox, video, mozilla

Since 2 days I have very nasty problem.[www.y-angel.com](http://www.y-angel.com).Except Mozilla every other browser open the videos in showreel and shorts buttons.I tried .mp4, .webm - they still are in the html and .ogg but nothing!Can someone help with this.I read a lot of stuff on the net but nothing helped me.So, can anyone?

```
 <video width="512px" height="288px" controls="controls"> 
   <source type="video/mp4" src="templates/angelyanakiev/videos/showreel.mp4"></source>
   <source type="video/webm" src="templates/angelyanakiev/videos/showreel.webm"></source>    
 </video>
```

Comment: Information is insufficient. Please provide some more details.

Comment: <video width="512px" height="288px" controls="controls">

    <source type="video/mp4" src="templates/angelyanakiev/videos/showreel.mp4"></source>
    <source type="video/webm" src="templates/angelyanakiev/videos/showreel.webm"></source>

</video>

This is the part of code that's not working in Mozilla and works in Opera, Safari, Chrome, IE11

Comment: sorry about the bad formatting I don't know how to make it right

Comment: i don't know much about this, but searching in [mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source), i saw that the controls attribute is used differently, and `</source>` is no necessary.